# Jboss (Wildfly) increase timeout for incoming request

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I want to increase the timeout for the incoming request in my jboss environment.
I always get current exception in my client after a few minutes in case of the incoming request takes more time.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Which parameters in the standalone.xml I have to adapt?

I am using Jboss EAP 7.3 and I am making rest calls using HttpClient from apache.
From client side I increase the timeout.

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(60 * 10 *1000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(60 * 10 *1000).setSocketTimeout(60 * 10 *1000).build();
```

Comment: What kind of request? What version of WildFly? Which client are you using?

Comment: Is it this config parameter `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000"`

Comment: I don't think so. /subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=no-request-timeout, value=600000) should do it as far as I understand

Comment: In which file I can find this, web.xml? I like to configure that one within JBOSS EAP, if possible?

Comment: That is a CLI command that will update your `standalonx.xml` file.